# Erro na atribuição do try e exception

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, exceção, semântica

Estamos com dificuldade na execução de uma atividade de **POO.**

Para executar o bloco de código onde o método que usamos apresenta uma saída inesperada **(Erro de semântica).**

```
 def acionamento(self, estado, nome_gerador): # acionar geradores
    try:
        self._nome == nome_gerador
        if estado == 'sim':
            print(nome_gerador, 'foi ligado!')
        if nome_gerador == 'G1':
            print('já esta ligado')
            raise Exception
    except Exception:
            print('o gerador não é gerenciado manualmente')
    if estado == 'nao':
        print(nome_gerador, 'solicitação cancelada!')
    else:
        pass
        #print('opção invalida!')
```

A resposta para  G1 está correta, quanto aos demais (G2,G3,G4) a saída que se espera é: G2 foi ligado/ou a solicitação foi cancelada.

```
 deseja ligar o gerador?

1.sim 
2.não

Digite: sim

nome do gerador: g1
o gerador não é gerenciado manualmente
```

Mas para os demais (G2,G3,G4) é preciso aparecer, exemplo "G2 foi ligado!"

```
    deseja ligar o gerador?

1.sim 
2.não

Digite: sim

nome do gerador: g2
o gerador não é gerenciado manualmente
```

Como vocês nos ajudariam a resolver este problema em anexo?

[image: Segue em anexo parte do exercício que explica o que deve ser feito.]

Comment: Leitura recomendada, [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas: Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/137387)

Comment: Amigos, poderia postar o código do objeto? Tá um pouco confuso esse código... Mas, observe a linha 11. Aquele "if" está identado corretamente?

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é assim:

```py
def acionamento(self, estado, nome_gerador): # acionar geradores
    self._nome = nome_gerador
    if nome_gerador is 'G1':
        print('já esta ligado')
        print('o gerador não é gerenciado manualmente')
    elif estado is 'sim':
        print(nome_gerador, 'foi ligado!')
    elif estado is 'nao':
        print(nome_gerador, 'solicitação cancelada!')
```

OU

```py
def acionamento(self, estado, nome_gerador): # acionar geradores
    self._nome = nome_gerador
    try:
        if nome_gerador is 'G1':
            print('já esta ligado')
            raise Exception
        elif estado is 'sim':
            print(nome_gerador, 'foi ligado!')
        elif estado is 'nao':
            print(nome_gerador, 'solicitação cancelada!')
    except Exception:
        print('o gerador não é gerenciado manualmente')
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, Alexandre

Comment: @fabiola-rosa-pedroso muito obrigado digo eu, Fabiola